# R - Split time series into time-only bins

Tags: r, datetime, time

I've a time series, in proper POSIX time, that I'd like to bin according **only** to time of day. I'm well able to bin things in, say, hours—but these hours are date-specific (for example: `2016-05-15 00:00:00` and `2016-05-16 00:00:00` are considered different bins).

I'd like to lump all `00:00:00 - 00:59:59` into one bin, all `01:00:00 - 01:59:59` into another bin, etc., but I can't find a means of doing this without including the date.

Does anyone have any idea as to how to do this? I've fooled around with `cut` and `lubridate` mostly to no avail.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop the date and deal only with the time component?

```
format(tt, "%H:%M:%S")
```

extracts the time component into a string, but it can be modified to further convert to any format your binning code handles. Alternatively, make the date the same prior to binning.

Answer (score 0):

This question would be much easier to answer with more context. I assume a single example ie:`2016-05-15 00:00:00` is a vector or data frame, so let's give it a name, ie: `>time<-2016-05-15 00:00:00`. You can gain some info on the format by checking the dimensions with `dim()` or `length()`. Or, if it is a nice vector with a header you can try using `names()`. This might enable you to find the elements you need to compare for your conditions.

Comment: It is really impossible to tell by what you have posted where you are getting you POSIX timestamps. Are they output objects of some function?

Comment: I'm getting my timestamps from some data I've collected—it's a time series. I'm afraid I'm not sure why where the data comes from is relevant, though; a method for binning a POSIX by time (and *not* date) should be standard across all POSIX stamps, shouldn't it?

Comment: well if it were some function i was going to recommend just typing ?"function name" and finding out if the output format or perhaps methods for retrieving the time only.

Comment: Ah! I see. I wish it were that easy, haha, but it isn't a function.

Comment: So you have a file full of timestamps or what?

Comment: Indeed, a file full of timestamps. Actually, I think I've found my answer below. It's not pretty, but I'll just drop the date, then reconvert to POSIX w/ the same date. I'll just omit the dates in my graph or something. :P